# Como cadastrar novo em autocomplete

Tags: jquery

Não sei se é o lugar certo para se perguntar, mas sempre vejo o seguinte componente em alguns sistemas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber, que plugin é esse?
Se for apenas o jquery ui autocomplete, como é feito aquele button para adicionar?

Comment: Os plugins [Typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) e [Selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) parecem ser o que você procura.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei também que plugin é esse (se colocares o link na pergunta podemos ser mais específicos) mas isso é bem simples de fazer. Basta ter uma div escondida que fica visivel no foco da primeira. Até dá para fazer só com CSS e selectores sibling.

Com algum trabalho no CSS pode dar-se o aspeto que se quiser.

Exemplo:

```css
div{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    
}

#meuInput:focus ~ div{
    opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="meuInput" />
<div><button>Adicione mais um!</button></div>
```

Pode ser também o caso de esse botão estar dentro da primeira (e única no exemplo) option de um select...

Comment: Oi @Sergio, não sei qual plugin é, eu vi em um sistema online que acessei, mas a sua solução me parece bem parecida com a deles, provavelmente é a mesma coisa que fazem, uma mescla com o que você fez + jquery ui autocomplete... obrigado pela resposta